# Ruby on Rails on elementary OS, uglifier error when starting server

Tags: web-development

I used rvm to install ruby 2.2.3. Then I installed rails 4.2.5. I create an app by `rails new ...` and then `cd` into it. I try to run it with `rails server`. And...

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
```

That's what I get. In my Gemfile I have `gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'.

What am I missing? It's my first try in RoR and it's getting a bit frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually having meteor installed doesn't count as having nodejs installed. nodejs is required for uglifier package, so simple: `apt install nodejs` resolves the issue.